# how to configure Jenkins on Unix and deployment in a remote machine windows

Tags: linux, node.js, windows, jenkins, continuous-deployment

I have an issue about Jenkins.I used a freestyle project not a maven project because it's a nodeJS project.

The Workflow is as below :

1. Jenkins trigger from GitLab Acceptation Merge Event.
2. Jenkins execute the build for testing integration.
3. execute shell command (linux) in actual linux OS.
4. Jenkins deploy the project after test success to a remote Windows Machine.

So what i want is how to deploy to a remote windows machine

Jenkins and Git are in the same machine (linux).
and deployment in a remote machine Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can plan to use a deployment automation solution like Xebialabs XL Deploy/IBM udeploy/CA Nolio as they are specialised products that will take care of a lot of the use cases related to deployment out of box and you do not have to create a scripted solution in Jenkins.

Comment: I have an existing architecture like this :
-Developer commit to Git repository.
-Jenkins run immediately after git commit trigger.
===> i have  a problem to how i can Deploy to a remote Windows Machine without using this tools just using jenkins

Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

you can use gitDeploy framework, that always does the job

Comment: thanks for your help,is this framework a plugin in Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can not deploy to a windows remote machine only using Jenkins. There is a Jenkins plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+CIFS+Plugin which might be worth looking, but I doubt if it will solve all the requirements. As it is for copying files to WINS share.

I would suggest you to have a look at Ansible (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html), you can install the ansible controller on the Linux along with Git & Jenkins and configure jenkins to trigger the ansible deploy on to the target windows machine.